# Django problem when clicking button to go from one page to another

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

Hi I am new to Django and I have written a code to go from one HTML code to another when a button is clicked but nothing happens when I click the button. Can someone help?

Below I have added my whole code and any hint is appreciated.

Here is `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from generator import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', views.home),
    url(r'^password/', views.password, name='password'),
]
```

Here is `views.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'generator/home.html')

def password(request):
    return render(request, 'generator/password.html')
```

Here is `home.html`:

```
<h1>Password Generator</h1>

<form action="{% url 'password' %}">
    <select name="length">
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Generate Password">
</form>
```

Here is `password.html`:

```
PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

`In home.html`

Inside the form, define `method="POST"`, and I suggest you remove the action part.

`In views.py`

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render 'home.html'
elif request.method == 'POST':
    # logic to generate / process password
    return redirect(reverse('password'))
```